# Getting Error [invalid_token_response] for spring security application

Tags: spring-security

I have created a sso login app but getting below error after successful login.

Login with OAuth 2.0
[invalid_token_response] An error occurred while attempting to retrieve the OAuth 2.0 Access Token Response: I/O error on POST request for "https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token": PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvf1T.png)

controller code:

```
@RestController
public class Application {

    @GetMapping("hello")
    ResponseEntity<String> hello() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Hello from secure Application");
    }
}
```

SecurityConfig class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2Login();

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

application.yml:

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          github:
            clientId: Iv1.7ab3f122765c5369
            clientSecret: 5f1a5fc41afbb8a0131f3de76235a998e78ed453
```

Homepage URL and Callback URL on github app is http://localhost:8080